# Get feedback on a possible answer to my question

Tags: support

My situation is that I asked a question and got several answers, but I found an answer myself, that I am not sure is a good one. If I want feedback on it, compared to the other answers, should I add it to my question, or put it forth as an answer, or as a comment on my question?

If I put it as an answer, would there be danger of getting downvotes on my answer even if I am not saying it is a definite answer?

Comment: It should be an answer. and, yes, there's certainly a possibility that users will vote on it's quality/usefulness.

Comment: So you want to get feedback on your answer, but you don't want to know if people don't like  your answer.  You have contradicted yourself.  If you want feedback on your answer, then that feedback might be that it's bad, but *you should still want to get that feedback*.

Comment: I recommend not qualifying your answer, if you post it, with statements like "this might not be a definite answer" or "this might not be good". 1) It's noise and 2) more likely to get down votes than prevent them if people interpret it as you not posting a real answer. If it solved your problem and you think it is useful, post it.

Comment: *I want feedback on it, compared to the other answers,* - Note that even if you post it and people vote on it, it won't necessarily be in comparison with existing answers. Over time having a higher/lower score than other answers would indicate people found your answer more/less useful but individual votes can't be read as saying your answer is better (or worse) than others.

Comment: @Servy I just don't have very high reputation yet, and didn't want to lose any just because I went about the process wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tacit way that we provide feedback to answers is through voting.  But, in general, the process you describe isn't different than what the other answerers went through:

- They found a question they could answer,
- They answered it, and
- Community members provided feedback in the form of votes and/or comments to determine if it was of decent quality.

Your answer won't be treated any differently through that cycle just because you're also the question asker.

Above all, be sure that you've done your homework on your issue, and make sure that it's an answer that can be easily understood.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend adding a self-answer to your question in this case because when you add an answer to any question, whether it's yours or someone else's, it should, to the best of your knowledge, *answer the question*. "I found a thing that works, but I don't know if it's a good idea" isn't generally a good answer. And while I agree with the comments on your question for the most part, adding a possibly bad answer is riskier for you as a new user than it would be for someone more established.

I think what you have described actually sounds like more of a question than an answer. If you found a different solution than the answers gave you, but you have some concerns about it, then it may be better to ask another question about it, as long as you have *specific* concerns about it that you can ask about *specifically*. (Not just "I don't know if this is a good way to do it." - that would rightfully be closed as too broad or primarily opinion-based.) It should be more like "Will [solution you found] cause [problem you're worried about it causing]?"

Of course, you should search before asking to see if your concern has already been addressed in another Q&A. And really, if you're not confident with a solution you've found, the best thing you can do is to experiment with it yourself. Test it in every relevant context you can think of with all kinds of different inputs. Try to break it. You may be able to figure out for yourself what problems it will have, which will be better for your understanding than just having someone else tell you. And if you get to the end of that and still have a question, you'll be able to ask a much better one.